# CREATE FUNCTION fails because column name is not specified, but aliases are defined

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-functions

I'm trying to create a function that is basically this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE FUNCTION [db].[do_stuff]
    (       
        @identifier nvarchar(255),
        @code nvarchar(255)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
    RETURN

    Select distinct
    (p.fname + ' ' + p.lname ) as fullname,
    p.person_no as ID, 
    p.username as login,
    tmp.title as rank,
    act.action_status as actstats,
    act.completion_date as completedon
    From db.CMT_PERSON p
        INNER JOIN db.TableA act on p.id=act.party_id
        INNER JOIN db.TableB tmp on act.id=tmp.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN db.TableC eq on tmp.id=eq.id2
    WHERE (p.person_no=@identifier or p.username=@identifier)
        and act.action_status=200
        and (Select top 1 ot.id as selected
             FROM db.TableG tc
                            INNER JOIN db.TableD e on tc.codeification_id=e.id
                            INNER JOIN db.TableE gc on gc.track_id=tc.id
                            INNER JOIN db.TableF ep on gc.id=ep.owner_id
                            INNER JOIN db.TableB ot on ot.id=ep.part_id
                        WHERE e.id=@code and (ot.id = tmp.id or ot.id = eq.id1))
            is not null 

    Order by act.completion_date desc
    FOR XML AUTO
    GO
```

Please note that every column this should return appears to have an alias, including the user-defined column "fullname".  Yet, I continue to get this error when attempting to build the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION failed because a column name is not specified for column 1.
```

Have I left an undefined column and I don't see it, or is something about the select statement causing a problem?

Comment: `for xml auto` transforms the result set into a blob of XML in an unnamed column.

Comment: This was, indeed, the problem, but we had to abandon this anyway and replace it temporarily with an inline sql string literal in c#. The programmer before me coded "defensively" to try to artificially build job security or to hide what they didn't know, and we discovered it will take a full refactor of a huge app to allow it to use anything other than CommandType.Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Damien_The_Unbeliever is right, the query you are running inside the function is not returning a table but an XML result. You may want to switch the type of function from Inline Table valued function to Scalar: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql